# Is it possible don't clean CocoaPods projects with Xcode clean

Tags: ios, xcode

Every time we think there are something compiling problems, we clean the Xcode project via command+shift+K which makes a very slow compiling then. 
So I'm thinking if there is a way to just clean some specified targets or a specified one. For example if  the CocoaPods projects doesn't change, I don't want to clean all of them.

Comment: Stop using `Cmd+Shift+K`.

Comment: @trojanfoe what's the replacement -_-||

Comment: You shouldn't have to use it to avoid compilation errors; I never need to.

Comment: Sometimes, when I modified xib, but the compiler cannot be aware of if, then I've to clean it. Does this happen to you ?  If I can avoid this situation, I may not use cmd+shift+K

Comment: No, I rarely have to clean because of build errors.  What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I usually upgrade my Xcode to latest version.   now is Version 6.4 (6E35b)
I think source code mostly the compiler can compile them well. But not good for xib. It happened to me several times. You are lucky

Comment: @trojanfoe maybe you don't use xib so often.  It happens a lot in our project in DEBUG scheme.

Comment: @aelam i've found that if i only modify values in storyboard Xcode don't see the file as changed and don't recompile it; but if you move something then it does. So the workaround is to slightly move something ininfluent (like the position of a uiviewcontroller) before building

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to clean only current Xcode project but not Cocoapods dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891333/any-way-to-clean-only-current-xcode-project-but-not-cocoapods-dependencies)