# Any way to clean only current Xcode project but not Cocoapods dependencies?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Relatively frequently I need to clean & rebuild because Swift starts to miss things up. But doing so, I am rebuilding Cocoapods dependencies, to no avail.
  Can I clean only the project, not the whole workspace?

Thanks,
Zsolt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Manage schemas -> Click Edit button for your active schema -> Select Build target -> Uncheck the "Find Implicit dependencies" checkbox .

Comment: It works, but every time you're going to *Archive* your project, you have to turn it back

Comment: It works with Xcode 10, in case you enable Legacy Build System. In any case, beware that you still need to build Pods target separately in case you build the project first time or after "Clean Build Folder".

Answer (score 3):

I tested the plugin cocoapods-binary and it is working pretty well:

- Plugin website: https://github.com/leavez/cocoapods-binary so you have pod as frameworks
- Referenced on cocoapods officiel website: https://guides.cocoapods.org/plugins/pre-compiling-dependencies.html

Comment: No longer supported I'd recommend Rugby

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use  [**Rugby**](https://github.com/swiftyfinch/Rugby).
It caches pods and keeps them on a different path.
So, you can clear DerivedData without losing your pods.